# C++ program, design using nested loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested, nested-loops

I have to make a program for generating the following output:

Example:

```
 & & & & & & &
   & & & & &
     & & &    
       &
```

What I have done so far:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int i,j,k,n;
    cout<<"How many rows?\n";
    cin>>n;
    for(i=n;i>0;i-=2)
    {
        cout<<"\n";

        for(k=(i+1)/2;k>0;--k)
        cout<<" ";

        for(j=1;j<=i;++j)
        cout<<"&";
    }
}
```

What the output comes:

```
    & & & & &
  & & &
&
```

Please correct me where I am making the mistake.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first try seems a bit complicated. I'd do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i,j,k,n;
    std::cout << "How many &'s in the start row?\n";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for(i=0; i < n; i+=2)
    {
        for(k=0 ; k < i; k++ )
        {
                std::cout << " ";
        }
        for(j=0; j<(n - i); ++j)
        {
                std::cout<<" &";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: compiler is giving "Declaration Syntax Error" in the first line

Comment: You are running an awfully old compiler. Change the include back to the old `#include<iostream.h>` and remove all the "std::"'s.

Comment: can u give me some link to download a better and improved version for running C++. I have windows 8.

Comment: Why don't you use the excellent VS 2012 express for Desktop (http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/deu/downloads) or the great GCC.

Comment: @ManojPandey It would be great, very relieving and a very good practice to also [accept the satisfying answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never. Try this simple solution :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char ch = '&';
  for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
    {
        if( i > j)
            cout << " ";
        else
            cout << ch;   
    }

    cout << ch;

    for(int j = 3; j >= 1; j--)
    {
        if( i > j)
            cout << " ";
        else
            cout << ch;   
    }

    cout << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems like the provided answer and comments have already solved this old problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class Design{
     public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<i;k++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for(int j=i;j<7-i;j++)
            {
                System.out.print("&");
            }
            System.out.println();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation for what the problem was that you are solving and how this code accomplishes that.

Comment: its better to provide some tech details like how its working instead of just posting code only.